# 'Autodesk.Forge' package with Net 6.0

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When adding package 'Autodesk.Forge into my VSCode project I get the below error.
`error: There are no versions available for the package 'Autodesk.Forge'.`

I'm following this tutorial with .NET 6 & VSCode.
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/setup

using Autodesk.Forge;
The type or namespace name 'Autodesk' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you ensure you have a nuget source registered with this command `dotnet nuget list source` ? You should get something like "Registered Sources: 1. nuget.org ...". If not you can add a nuget source like that `dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: what's your OS? we tested that tutorial for Windows & Mac (x86 & ARM)

Comment: I added the nuget.org resource which resolved the error for me on my Windows OS. Additionally, I'm facing some error when navigating to http://localhost:8080/api/hubs to see the hubs listed as json. I guess, I need to first integrate the Forge app I created with my BIM 360 account. I've Project Admin role on many projects but I don't see the Account Admin module to add the app. Can an existing admin integrate the app on my behalf with their account?

Comment: Nice if my comment solved your problem. Please create another question if you have others errors.